# How to create this feature using css or jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to create an expandable div based on the following diagram.

[image: I tried to use the following fiddl]e, https://jsfiddle.net/z7phyztx/  , but was unsuccessful in creating the similar effect.

```js
$('.detail').hide()

$('.mydiv li').click(function() {
  var pos = $(this).offset();
  $('.detail').show();
  $('.detail').offset(pos);

});
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I've updated the answer so its more smooth now

Answer (score 1):

The example I made below might be what you are looking for.

Updated it to be way more smooth now. Take a look

```js
var open = false;
$(".mydiv li").click(function() {
  var index = $(".mydiv li").index(this);
var $this = $(this)

  function show_popup(callback) {
    $(".detail").toggle("slow", function() {
      open = open ? false : true;
    });
  };
  if (index % 2 === 0) {
    if (open) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        show_popup($(".detail").insertAfter($(".mydiv li").eq((index + 1))))
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      $(".detail").insertAfter($(".mydiv li").eq((index + 1)))
    }
  } else {
    if (open) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        show_popup($(".detail").insertAfter($(".mydiv li").eq(index)))
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      $(".detail").insertAfter($(".mydiv li").eq(index))
    }
  }
  $(".detail").toggle("slow", function() {
    $(this).text($($this).attr("data-context"))
    open = open ? false : true;
  });
});
```

```css
.maindiv {
  max-width: 450px
}

.mydiv {
  width: 100%
}

.mydiv li {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px
}

.detail {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="maindiv">
  <ul class="mydiv">

    <li data-context="SOME TEXT 1">sdfdsf</li>
    <li data-context="SOME TEXT 2">sdfdsf</li>
    <li data-context="SOME TEXT 3">sdfdsf</li>
    <li data-context="SOME TEXT 4">sdfdsf</li>
    <div class="detail"></div>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Am trying to use your code to make the exact function/display am looking. Shall update you soon. Thank you  :)

Comment: @Gopa I've added a way you can add data to the li and show that data in the box that pops up

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be using a list to do this. So i've changed the code structure to suit and given the old 'li' a class name 'item'. I also pass through a data attribute to help identify the currently selected item.

The way it works is that if the current selected item is clicked, the details div will hide, otherwise it will be revealed. If it is already open but a different item is clicked, it will remain open.

https://jsfiddle.net/z7phyztx/16/

```
<script>
$(".mydiv .item").click(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
    $('.item').removeClass('active');
    $(".detail").hide("slow", function() {
      // Animation complete.
    });
    return false;
  }
  $('.item').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(".detail").show("slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
    $(this).attr('data-position', $this.data('position'));
  });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done via both `CSS3` and `jQuery`, but I am explaining with `jQuery`.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.child').on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).closest('.parent').find('.new-child').remove();
    if ($(this).closest('.parent').find('.new-child').length == 0) {
      $(this).addClass('clicked');
      $(this).closest('.parent').append('<div class="new-child hide" />');
      $('.new-child').fadeIn();
    }
 });
```

**CSS:**

```
.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 20px;
}

.child:hover {
  background: #cfcfcf;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.parent::after,
.new-child::before {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  clear: both;
}

.new-child {
  clear: both;
  width: 442px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.clicked {
  background: #cfcfcf;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/srgohfu4/)